# File uploading issue on glassfish server

Tags: file, upload, glassfish, glassfish-3

I have written a small ruby application to upload file using multipart-form.
This works fine on webrick server and glassfish gem. But deploying this application 
on glassfish v2.1.1 works only for small files upto 50kb and will show error page 
for larger files.

Anybody could please help me to sort out this issue.

thanks
Vicky

Answer (score 0):

50kb or 5 mb?  Try experimenting with  in your domain.xml for the http-listener sections.